# How to match different writings of a key name in python?

Tags: python

I need to match keys against various possible writings of a key name and return the corresponding value.

How is it possible to improve the function I wrote, in a way that only one line is nessessary per key, e.g. (10 bar|10 ATM|100m|100 m) ?

```
def water(i): 
    switcher={
            'bis 10 bar' : 127,      
            '10 bar' : 127, 
            '10 ATM' : 127,       
            '100m' : 127,      
            '100 m' : 127,      
            '300m' : 129,      
            '300 m' : 129,      
            'bis 30 bar' : 129,      
            '30 bar' : 129,      
         }
    for k, v in switcher.items():
        if k.lower() in i.lower():
            return v
    return "Invalid: " + i

print water('10 ATM');
```

The function will return the value for each key if present, if not it will return invalid: +key.

So in the case of `print water('10 ATM');` it will return 127

I am looking for a way to match different writing styles of the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re` to specify patterns. This will work for your example

```
import re
switcher = {
    re.compile('.*10.*'):127,
    re.compile('.*30.*'):129
}

def water(string):
    for i in switcher.keys():
        if re.match(i,string):
            return switcher[i]
    return "Invalid"
```

You could very well group the different patterns into a single list and do a check on the list instead. But `re` will give you better pattern matching if that's what you want.

Comment: Why did you place the switcher outside of the function? I have many more functions like this (e.g. color) so it would be much better to have one clean function per attribute. Could this also be inside the function? Actually  thinking about this, Maybe I could remove all functions and just keep all the keys in one?

Comment: Yea sure it would still work if it is inside the function.

Comment: This would work well inside the function as well. However note that in this example any string containing '10' would return 127 and any string containing '30' would return 129. 
If this is what you're after the above is a great solution.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not terribly elegant, but you could try:

```
def water(i): 
    if i in ['bis 10 bar', '10 bar', '10 ATM', '100m', '100 m']:
        return 127
    elif i in ['300m', '300 m, 'bis 30 bar', '30 bar']:
        return 129
    else:
        return "Invalid: " + i
```

This could also be further generalized to take into consideration lower/upper case and spaces:

```
def water(i): 
    j = i.replace(" ", "").lower()
    if j in ['bis10bar', '10bar', '10atm', '100m']:
        return 127
    elif j in ['bis30bar', '30bar', '30atm', '300m']:
        return 129
    else:
        return "Invalid: " + i
```

However note the latter will allow for any variation of spacing.
If you wish to restrict this to only specific cases, you can remove the `.replace(" ", "")` from the second example and make the cases in the lists more specific.

Comment: What will be the output for `'10 atm'`?

Comment: this is just an example, based on the OP's original post. The lists could of course be changed as necessary

Comment: again, a general example, but edited to account for case and spacing

Answer (score 0):

If a specific substring (or pattern) can be found in each group and if you can accept to go as soon as the substring is present you can try to search for it. For example here you could do

```
if '10' in i:
    return 127
elif '30' in i:
    return i
else:
    return "Invalid: " + i
```

But it would accept keys other that those from your lists...

Comment: What is `key`? Did you mean to write `i` instead?

Comment: @kiner_shah: Of course I meant `i`. Thanks for noticing! Post edited...

Answer (score 0):

```
def water(i): 
    switcher={
            'bis 10 bar' : 127,      
            '10 bar' : 127, 
            '10 ATM' : 127,       
            '100m' : 127,      
            '100 m' : 127,      
            '300m' : 129,      
            '300 m' : 129,      
            'bis 30 bar' : 129,      
            '30 bar' : 129,      
         }
    if i in switcher:
        return switcher[i]
    elif i.lower() in switcher:
        return switcher[i.lower()]
    return "Invalid: " + i

print water('10 ATM')
```

I replaced the `for` loop with `if-else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new dictionary with aliases to the original switcher keys:

```
def water(i):
    switcher = {
        10: 127,
        30: 129
    }
    aliases = {
        10: ['bis 10 bar', '10 bar'],
        30: ['300m', '30 bar']
    }
    for k, v in aliases.items():
        if i.lower() in v:
            return switcher[k]
    return 'invalid: ' + i
```

Answer (score 0):

> a way that only one line is nessessary per key (...) looking for a way to match different writing styles of the key

**Use a custom dictionary**

Here's an approach that works like a dictionary and is easy to reuse for your other scenarios (e.g. color).

```
# definition, replacing the water function
water = FuzzyDict({
    'bis 10 bar|10.?bar|10 ATM|100.?m' : 127,
    '300.?m|bis 30 bar|30 bar': 129
})
```

This way you can use `water` as you would a normal dictionary, you don't even need a function anymore, and you can easily use `water` to test if an item is stored, e.g. using `if <query> in water`:

```
# example use
water['bis 10 bar'], water['10 bar'], water['10 ATM'], water['300m'], water['300 m']
=> (127, 127, 127, 129, 129)
'bis 10 bar' in water, 'red color' in water
=> (True, False)
```

**One-time implementation of FuzzyDict**

The `FuzzyDict` is implemented as follows. Put this code in a separate module `fuzzydict.py`, then forget about it -- your actual code looks like the demo above.

How does this work? `FuzzyDict` overrides the `__getitem__` method of a normal dictionary to parse the regular expressions provided as keys. To make this work efficiently, the patterns are compiled on definition of entries and the first match among all patterns is used.

```
import re 

class FuzzyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._patterns = {}
        if len(args):
            for data in args:
                for k, v in data.iteritems():
                    self[k] = v
        super(FuzzyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        for pk, p in self._patterns.iteritems():
            if p.match(k):
                k = pk
                break
        return super(FuzzyDict, self).__getitem__(k)

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if not k in self._patterns:
            p = re.compile(k)
            self._patterns[k] = p 
        super(FuzzyDict, self).__setitem__(k, v)

    def __contains__(self, k):
        try:
            self[k]
        except:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Notes

- the class implementation is not fully complete but matches the purpose as per the question.
- the `_patterns` helper dict matches patterns to actual dict keys. This way `FuzzyDict.keys()` returns the keys as specified, not the compiled patterns (as is the case in @Omar Sabade's solution). This makes it easier to debug/work with the keys outside of `__getitem__`.